# Sort photos by view count on Picasa Web

Tags: picasa-web-albums

How can I sort photos by view count on Picasa Web?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't. You can sort your photos only by **Name**, **Date**, or **Size**.

Source: [Picasa and Picasa Web Albums Help](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=15186)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can.

Using the button bar below the menu, select "**View Options**" (the small triangle)

[image: View Options Button]

That brings up a drop down menu. From there, select "**Sort People By Amount**".

Comment: The question is about Picasa Web, not Picasa.